# decltype(*&fun) is strange?

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, decltype

I have:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdio.h>

void f() { printf("foo\n"); }

int main()
{
  printf("%d %d %d\n",
    std::is_same<decltype(*&f),decltype(f)>::value,
    std::is_function<decltype(*&f)>::value,
    std::is_function<decltype(f)>::value);
  (*&f)();
  return 0;
}
```

which yields

```
0 0 1
foo
```

on g++ 4.6.1 and 4.7.0.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I bet `*&f` is a reference type.

Comment: Bingo! std::remove_reference<...> does the trick!

Answer (score 13):

It's important to note that `decltype` has two meanings: it can be used to find the declared type (hence its name) of an *entity*, or it can be used to inspect an *expression*. I'm using entity loosely here and am not referring to any term of the Standard but to put it simply it could be a variable, a function, or (strangely enough in my opinion) a member access. The type that is returned when an expression is examined is more often than not different from the type of the expression itself, thus:

```
int i;
void foo();
struct { int i; } t;

static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( i ),     int>::value,       "" );
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( foo ),   void()>::value,    "" );
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( t.i ),   int>::value,       "" );

static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( (i) ),   int&>::value,      "" );
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( (foo) ), void(&)()>::value, "" );
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( (t.i) ), int&>::value,      "" );
```

Note how this works for functions, and hence that in your case `decltype(*&f)` is the same as `decltype( (f) )`, not `decltype(f)`.

Comment: Tgis is half the truth though. the type of the expression (f) is not of reference type. no expression is of reference type.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You're right of course. I don't know what kind of disclaimer to put though -- I think my little fiction is *not* a simplification of how `decltype` is specified. It is, however, a simplification of how value category, references and reference types interact.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I've rollbacked because I've designed my answer to not describe the complete behaviour of `decltype`. It is sufficient (IMO) to point out that `decltype(name)` is different from `decltype( (name) )` to answer the question. Adding more details would be more appropriate for a question about the inner workings of `decltype`. However I decided on an appropriate disclaimer to point out that the snippets are only meant to be illustrative of *some* of the behaviour of `decltype`.

Comment: Although my answer does feel incomplete without a link to a nice resource to the complete behaviour of `decltype`, for the curious.

Comment: Now the answer is correct. fwiw the spec defines what an entity is. It can be a value, object, function, template, reference, type etc pp. That is, anything that "exists". A member access is not an entity but it can be used to refer to an entity (object, reference, function, value (if there is no more direct entity kind "enumerator", havent got the spec here) or template).