# C++11 template instantiation errors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

I have two piece of code:

1)

```
 template< class T >
   auto min( T a, T b ) -> decltype(a)
   {
      return a < b ? a : b;
   }




int main()
{
    struct A{};
    auto x = min( 2, 3 ) ;// success

    auto a = A{};
    auto b = A{};
    auto c = min(a,b);// here is error    
}
```

http://ideone.com/cXgnPy

And
2)

```
    template< class T >
    auto min(T a, T b ) ->decltype(a<b, a)
   {
      return a < b ? a : b;
   }



int main()
{
        struct A{};
        auto x = min( 2, 3 ) ;// success
        auto a = A{};
        auto b = A{};
        auto c = min(a,b);// here is another error    
}
```

http://ideone.com/Rfs4Lv

What is different first and second case errors? Which is that better?

UPD: which  'min' implementations is better?

Comment: 1) You don't mention the error you're getting. 2) I'm willing to bet it's because you don't have `operator<` defined for your struct as seen in your example code.

Comment: What would you expect to be the outcome of `a<b` for struct `A`? How should the compiler know if you don't declare the operator?

Comment: **Don't abuse of the `auto` keyword**. Your function `min()` compares to instances of the same type, so there is no reason at all to use a trailing return type. The return type is clearly `T`. Also note that the second version, which uses `decltype(a < b , a)` as return type its exactly the same as in the first version (`decltype(a)`): `a < b,a` is an expression which uses the comma operator, which evaluates the first operand, discards the result, and evaluates and returns the value of the second operand.

Comment: Have you written that pieces of code or is something you have found on Internet?

Comment: What is wrong with std::min?

Comment: what is the use of comparing two default constructed objects of same type? they will end up being the same.

Comment: @Koushik the point of the question is the `min()` function template. The code of main is only examples of its use. So OP tested the function  with a simple custom type: An empty struct.

Comment: @NeilKirk Unrelated to the question, but it doesn't properly work with variadic arguments and doesn't produce its result at compile-time if possible (i.e. `constexpr`).

Answer (score 2):

As your compiler probably told you, the problem is that there is no match for the `operator<` for the operands `A` and `A`. `int` has this operator built-in, but you need to declare one yourself for your own classes:

```
struct A
{
    A(int a) : a(a) {}

    bool operator<(A const & rhs)
    {
        return a < rhs.a;
    }

    int a;
};
```

Then `min(A(1), A(2))` becomes a valid call. The problem is the same for both code snippets you provided.

**Which `min` implementation is better?**

I wouldn't choose either. First, there is no need for the late decision of return type, you could just

```
template <typename T>
T min(T a, T b)
{ return a < b ? a : b; }
```

and the second code snippet is just obfuscating the same code, which is even worse. Also there is `std::min` in the `<algorithm>` header.

Answer (score 1):

struct A does not operator< defined while int has

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment: **Don't abuse of the auto keyword**. Your function `min()` compares two instances of the same type, so there is no reason at all to use a trailing return type. The return type is clearly `T`.
The seond version uses the comma operator, which evaluates and discards the first operand, and evaluates and returns the second operand. When you uses `decltype` with an expression instead of an entity, as in this case, it returns the return type of the expression. So this version returns `T&` instead of `T`.

So the answer is: **The second version is better, because avoids a copy. But both versions are a bad and unnecesary case of the use of triling return type**. The good approach is to return `T`:

```
template<typename T>
T& min(const T& lhs , const T& rhs) 
{
    return lhs < rhs ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

Comment: @LucDanton if thats not the comma operator, and is not evaluated to `a` (`t` in your example) whats this? Your example puzzled me :)

Comment: [In so many words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467791/decltypefun-is-strange/9469979#9469979), `decltype` can perform one of two, distinct things -- either inspect the type of an entity, or the type of an expression. It so happens that in this case the two uses do two different things, with two different results.

Comment: [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) says *"The return type and value category of the comma operator are exactly the return type and the value category of the second operand, E2."* So where is the difference between the first case and the second case?

Comment: @LucDanton thanks, now I understand. Thanks for waste you time clearing my missunderstandings.